# How to set the default value of `submodule.<name>.ignore`

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-config

The default value of `submodule.<name>.ignore` is `none`, but I would much prefer `dirty` to be the default value in my global configuration.  However, when I set `submodule.ignore` to `dirty` in my `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`, I do not see it taking effect in superprojects spread across my system.  Furthermore, I have confirmed that I do not have local configuration or `.gitmodules` overriding the global value.

Is there a way to set a new default for `submodule.<name>.ignore`, or am I stuck with some kind of incantation of `git submodule foreach` to set `submodule.<name>.ignore` for each submodule in a superproject, and then doing this in each superproject on my system?  I am using git version 2.17.0.

Comment: The global for `git status` is in `status.submoduleSummary`, not `submodule.ignore`. You can also use `--ignore-submodules=dirty`. Or is this for the status produced by `git commit`?

Comment: @torek Thanks for bringing that to my attention. Reading the docs for `status.submoduleSummary` revealed the answer to my question, which pertained to both `git status` and `git commit` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `diff.ignoreSubmodules` option is what I was looking for.  Its effects are seen both in `git status` and `git commit`, in the same fashion as what you'd expect from setting `submodule.<name>.ignore`.